# How to use the default laravel change using a different database name?

Tags: php, laravel

Laravel by default asks for a DB called "laravel" and a users table called "users", but I named them in a different way and I want to make it works. Below the error it gives me:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->hasFile('file'))
    {
        $file = $request->file('file');
        $name = time();
        $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $fileName = $name . '.' . $extension;
        $file->move(public_path('files/criticSuggestions'), $fileName);
    }
    SubCriticSuggestion::create([
        'user_id' => auth()->id(),
        'text' => $request->text,
        'critic_suggestion_id' => $request->critic_suggestion_id,
        'file' => $fileName
    ]);
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

I get this error

> Undefined variable: fileName

Comment: You can update database name in .env file

Comment: `$fileName` only exists if there is a file in the request. If the file is optional, initialize `$fileName` before your if check so that it exists even if there is no file. If the file is not optional, move your create statement inside of the if check.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely did not get inside the condition where the variable is declared $fileName

In add dd(). if it works, then everything is ok

```
if ($request->hasFile('file'))
    {
        dd('We here');

        $file = $request->file('file');
        $name = time();
        $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $fileName = $name . '.' . $extension;
        $file->move(public_path('files/criticSuggestions'), $fileName);
    }
```

In .env change db name

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=YOUR_DB_NAME
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root
```

Comment: I put `dd` after `if`, but I see ` Undefined variable: fileName ` error again now, my problem did not solve yet.

Comment: @DeveloperLaravel Answer - You most likely did not get inside the condition where the variable is declared as $fileName.

Comment: @DeveloperLaravel you have to send post request with parameter file.check the name of your input. It should be = file